# Stripe iOS didCreatePaymentResult never gets called

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

The problem seems simple, didCreatePaymentResult never gets called.

BUT, in my old sample project, taken from your iOS example for payment intent, that `didCreatePaymentResult` gets called every single time I create or select a card, here's the repo of the working project: https://github.com/glennposadas/stripe-example-ios-nodejs

BUT again, my main concern is my current project.

I use **v19.2.0** in both of these projects, I even tried the **v19.3.0**.

I wanted to use **Stripe Charge** really, but I believe Stripe does not support Apple pay for that. So I have no choice but to use **Stripe Payment Intent**.

---

**CoreService.swift** (conforms to STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider)

```
extension CoreService: STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider {
    func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
        orderServiceProvider.request(.requestEphemeralKey(stripeAPIVersion: apiVersion)) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case let .success(response):
                guard let json = ((try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data, options: []) as? [String : Any]) as [String : Any]??) else {
                    completion(nil, NSError(domain: "Error parsing stripe data", code: 300, userInfo: nil))
                    return
                }
                
                completion(json, nil)
                
            default:
                UIViewController.current()?.alert(title: "Error stripe", okayButtonTitle: "OK", withBlock: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PaymentController.swift**

```
class PaymentViewController: BaseViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Properties

    private var paymentContext: STPPaymentContext!
    private let paymentConstantValue: Int = 3000
    
    // MARK: - Functions
    // MARK: Overrides
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.setupStripe()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        self.hideNavBar(animated: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func creditCardButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.paymentContext.presentPaymentOptionsViewController()
    }
    
    private func setupStripe() {
        let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared()
        config.appleMerchantIdentifier = "merchant.com.gsample.app"
        config.companyName = "Scoutd LLC"
        config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .none
        config.requiredShippingAddressFields = .none
        config.additionalPaymentOptions = .applePay
        
        let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: CoreService())
        
        let paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(
            customerContext: customerContext,
            configuration: config,
            theme: STPTheme.default()
        )
        
        let userInformation = STPUserInformation()
        paymentContext.prefilledInformation = userInformation
        paymentContext.paymentAmount = self.paymentConstantValue
        paymentContext.paymentCurrency = "usd"
        
        self.paymentContext = paymentContext
        
        self.paymentContext.delegate = self
        self.paymentContext.hostViewController = self
    }
}

// MARK: - STPPaymentContextDelegate

extension PaymentViewController: STPPaymentContextDelegate {
    func paymentContextDidChange(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext) {
        print("paymentContextDidChange")
    }
    
    func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
        // error alert....
    }
    
    func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didCreatePaymentResult paymentResult: STPPaymentResult, completion: @escaping STPPaymentStatusBlock) {
        print("didCreatePaymentResult ✅")
    }
    
    func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFinishWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
        switch status {
        case .success:
            // success
        case .error:
            // error alert....
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED! This should help engineers struggling with Stripe implementation in the future.

So in my case, I have two buttons:

1. Apple Pay
2. Credit card.

The absolute solution for me is handle the `selectedPaymentOption` of the `paymentContext`.

Scenarios:

1. If the apple pay button is tapped, present apple pay sheet and don't present add/select card UI of Stripe.
2. If the credit card button is tapped, don't present apple pay sheet and instead present select card.
3. Related to #2, call `requestPayment()` if there's a selected option.

Voila! The `didCreatePaymentResult` now gets invoked!

```
// MARK: IBActions

@IBAction func applePayButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if self.paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption is STPApplePayPaymentOption {
        self.paymentContext.requestPayment()
    }
}

@IBAction func creditCardButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if let selectedPaymentOption = self.paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption,
        !(selectedPaymentOption is STPApplePayPaymentOption) {
        
        self.paymentContext.requestPayment()
        return
    }
    
    self.paymentContext.presentPaymentOptionsViewController()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for following up with your solution!